# Problemas com consulta SQL com Knex em React

Tags: sql, react

Seguinte eu tenho duas tabelas uma de students e outra de users e estou tentando fazer uma chamada de login simples, verificando o email e o password do user através da chave estrangeira entre students e user. Porém só esta me retornando vazio, alguem poderia me ajudar?

```
    async create(request, response) {
    const { email, password } = request.body;

    const type = 's'; 


    const student = await connection('users as u')
        .innerJoin('students as s')
        .where('s.email', email)
        .andWhere('s.id', 'u.student_id')
        .andWhere('u.password', password)
        .andWhere('u.type', type)
        .select('*')
        

        console.log(student);   

        if(!student) {
             return response.status(400).json({ error: 'No Student found with this Email' });
        }

        return response.json(null);
}
```

Fiz a alteração como você disse Thainam mas ainda está retornando vazio. A estrutura agora está assim

```
const student = await connection('users as u')
        .innerJoin('students as s', function(){
            this.on('s.cpf', '=', 'u.student_id')
        })
        .where('s.email', email)
        .andWhere('s.cpf', 'u.student_id')
        .andWhere('u.password', password)
        .andWhere('u.type', type)
        .select('s.email')
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, amigo. Não está faltando você referenciar o innerJoin com o ON ?

Knex não é minha área, mas olhando rapidamente a documentação, eles dão este exemplo:

```
.innerJoin('accounts', function() {
  this.on('accounts.id', '=', 'users.account_id').orOn('accounts.owner_id', '=', 'users.id')
})
```

Outra dica, referencie o ' * ' para não dar conflito de campos.  Ex: .select('u.*')

Referência: http://knexjs.org/#Builder-innerJoin